# Add drive mapping via GPO without domain on WinSrv2012r2

Tags: shell-script, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to WinSrv2012r2 and all the GPO stuff.

Now my problem is, I am using a batchfile to create a drive mapping (`s:`)

Actually I dont want to put this into autostart because every user needs this to get mapped, also new created users...

**Is it possible to add a GPO that the system automaticly creates the mapping for all users on logon?
If yes, how can I do this?**

I've been searching the net for two days now and can't find anything that helps me to solve my problem. Also I dont think I'm the first one trying this! :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to create a GPO that creates a map network drive on the user login there are multiple methods tho :

1. **Open group policy management console**
2. **Create a new group policy object under the specified OU ( if it is a computer OU I suggest you add loopback processing mode to merged, if it is on the user OU which I prefer there is no need to make any modification ) and let's call it map network drive**
3. **Now right click on that group policy which we just created and click edit and navigate to User configuration -> preference -> and expand windows settings**
4. **Now select drive maps right click new -> mapped drive**
5. **Now you can configure your mapped drive as you wish , you can create , replace , delete or update mapped drives depends on your needs and the user will login with a mapped drive you already set the path and letter to**
   For further info on configuring mapped drives please visit [Creating map network drives via gpo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902(v=ws.11).aspx)

Now the second option you have which is exhausting and I do not recommend is :

1. **Navigate to your active directory**
2. **Go to selected users OU**
3. **Right click properties on the users you wish to add map network drives to ( individually I recommend )**
4. **Navigate to profile tab**
5. **Under the home folder you can assign the home path to the mapped network drive for each user with letters**

For more info setting it up through active directory please visit this link 
[Adding home folder to users through active directory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816313)